# Use Textfield as a Variable Possible ? don't know

Tags: reporting-services, expression, textfield

I am currently trying to do the following.
I have 2 Textfields, One is Taken from the Dataset (in the Pictures below i have used 400 as a plain number to make things more straight Forward).
now what i want is for one of them to be used as a Variable (not sure if this is the right Term)
i want the value that Text1 is given to automatically be divided from Text2.
Below you will see the Text1 (named Divide) Properties.
[image: Text 1]

and this is Text2 where I am trying to use the Value of Text 1:

[image: Text2]

I Know everything about having to Convert The field into an Int or some Number, and everything,
what i don't get is how I am supposed to use Textfield1 in Textfield2 ?
Thanks for your Answers in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer, thanks again to Visakh16

```
=400/ReportItems!Divide.value
```

and here the link: [Use Textfield as a Variable Possible ? - Social MSDN](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bbb29c7a-87c0-41f6-921e-2fc1974ff8a6/use-textfield-as-a-variable-possible-dont-know?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Answer (score 0):

What programming language is that?
if it's C# you can do something like:

```
int x = int.Parse(Text2.Text);
```

this will convert the string of **Text2** (Textfield) to an integer,

if it's java it would be like:

```
 int x = Integer.parseInt(Text2.getText());
```

But if the user enter some character that isn't a number the problem will crash.

Comment: I know how to convert them, i want to know how to use it, it's not really a language, it's an SSRS expression

Comment: how to use? like what?
What you do with that is equal that number to a variable and then you use that variable for your methods

Comment: I wasn't talking about Methods at all, this is the SSRS Forum I believe, i havn't tagged C#, anyways see the Answer below